# Is possible overwriting a Doctrine model in Symfony?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

is possible overwriting a Doctrine model in Symfony?

I'm trying no change a "notnull" property, but i can get it..

In 'plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/config/doctrine/schema.yml':

```
sfGuardUser:
   actAs: [Timestampable]
   columns:
     id:
       type: integer(4)
       primary: true
       autoincrement: true
     username:
       type: string(128)
       notnull: true    
       unique: true
#...
```

And in 'config/doctrine/schema.yml':

```
sfGuardUser:
   columns:
     username:
       type: string(128)
       notnull: false
       unique: true
```

Then "build-all-reload" but it doesn't change..

Any idea?

Javi

Comment: What version are you on? In 1.4+ you can overwrite schemas.

Comment: sf 1.2. Thats the reason..Is there any way to operate schemas overwriting in sf 1.2 o 1.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As coronatus said, you can overwrite schemas in Symfony 1.4, you should be able to do this in Symfony 1.3 also if you want to upgrade your project without removing all deprecated 1.2 stuff.